# Jenkins - Unable to locate requirements.txt file

Tags: jenkins

Im trying to create a jenkins pipeline and the first step in the project is to create a virtualenvironment.

Here is the below steps thats been executed.

```
stage('create virtualenvironment') {
                sh '''
                       echo $WORKSPACE
                       echo $PATH
                       set +e
                       export PATH=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv:$PATH
                       export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
                       export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
                       source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
                       rmvirtualenv testproject
                       mkvirtualenv testproject
                       pip install --upgrade pip
                       #pip install -r requirements.txt -r dev-requirements.txt
                       pip install -r requirements.txt
                       make clean
                   '''

        }
```

when this job runs I get this error -

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the file located ?? unless the file is located in the current directory only then will it work the way you have mentioned otherwise you can try

**/*requirements.txt or DirectoryOfFile/requirements.txt

If all of the above fails just give the absolute path and it should work

Hope it helps :)